# MATLAB SIMULINK - Add Sine wave to Wav file

Tags: matlab, simulink, trigonometry

Hi I am totally new to matlab, and I'm using the dsp tool box within simulink. Using the drag and drop function from the tool box I want to find the mid frequency of a wav file and put a sine wave there to corrupt the sound. I have no clue how to do this. Would this be done using an add function?

the image below is my attempt at this, is this the correct method?

[image]

Comment: Yes. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should defiantly work my young padwan

Comment: Now you have the knowledge to defeat the dark side of the sine wave